# EE Version 2.11.7 - 500 Internal Server Error after Publishing Entry

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades, error-500

We recently upgraded our EE2 clients to the latest version 2.11.7
After logging in and publishing/editing an entry the site goes down with a 500 Internal Server Error (front end and control panel.) 
After clearing cookies the site and CP come back up, and the change was successfully made.

This is happening to ALL the clients we upgraded (several of them), so we can confirm it is not limited to a specific extension or module error.

If anyone can help it's much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug; please report it: https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs 
2.11.7 Came out very recently, so maybe it is an unreported bug.

Comment: Pls let us know which version of php your server is running and what the previous EE version(s) where too

Comment: Previous version of EE was 2.11.4 and the version of php our server is running is 5.5.25

Comment: Are you able to access static files like images or CSS still, or has it essentially taken the whole site down? Have you checked your servers error logs to get a detailed reason for the error? Internal Server Errors are either web server config, and the request doesn't even spin up PHP, or the PHP thread is crashing and cannot send useful errors as a response. Your server's error logs should have full details.

Comment: Yes we are still able to access images. We are checking our server error logs now.

Comment: We just checked and we have no errors AT ALL logged on any of the sites we upgraded - logged to the error log.   We've tested on multiple sites, and none are logging anything to the apache error log.

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact the host / sysadmin to make sure that server errors are being logged. That logging happens apart from PHP, so ExpressionEngine would not be involved in whether or not the server is properly logging 500 errors, et al.

Comment: I recently got 500 errors after doing some server (cPanel) and EE upgrades. Everything was due to PHP running out of memory. Somehow, easyapache had reset the PHP memory limit back down to 32MB. I bumped it up and everything ran fine.